# Is the union Non Recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

Define languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ as follows :

$L_0 = \{\langle M, w, 0 \rangle \mid M \text{ halts on }w\} $

$L_1 = \{\langle M, w, 1 \rangle \mid M \text{ does not halts on }w\}$

Here $\langle M, w, i \rangle$ is a triplet, whose first component $M$ is an encoding of a Turing
Machine, second component $ w$ is a string, and third component $i$  is a bit.

Let $L = L_0 ∪ L_1$. Which of the following is true?

1. $L$ is recursively enumerable, but $L'$ is not
2. $L'$ is recursively enumerable, but $ L$ is not
3. Both $L$ and $L'$ are recursive
4. Neither $L$ nor $L'$ is recursively enumerable

---

I know that 
$L_0$ is recursively enumerable and $L_1$ is non recursively enumerable but their union is what I'm confused with .

I'm not sure though, but I am unable to design TM for $L$ which makes me think that it is not recursively enumerable ?

Comment: What is $L'$? The complement of $L$?

Comment: Hint: if $L$ is r.e., can you solve the halting problem then?

Comment: @AndrejBauer yes, L' is the complement of L.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sorry, I didn't get your second comment.

Comment: Have you tried crafting some reduction?

Comment: @chi We have not yet studied reduction.

Comment: A hint is not supposed to be immediately obvious. Let me walk over to the institute, and you think about it some more, ok?

Comment: You should reason by contradiction then. Assume you have a decider (or semidecider) for the union. Can you exploit that to craft a (semi-)decider for $L_i$? For instance, if we could craft a semidecider for $L_1$, we would get a contradiction because $L_1$ is not r.e., as you said.

Comment: @AndrejBauer yes, it is NON RE otherwise halting problem will be solved . I got your meaning .

Comment: @Garrick: excellent.